# Compare executable output to text file using grep

Tags: shell, testing, grep

I need a automated method to compare my C++ standard output to the 'expected output' test case files.

In the past I used a shell script that would execute my program by passing input, then comparing the output with grep to plain text. The problem now is that my output spans multiple lines and has much more test cases, making it much easier to compare expected output to a text file.

The test script I used in the past:
    cd /
    cd media/psf/Home/Developer/Project/
    make

```
./a.out < tests/test01.txt | grep 'EXPECTED OUTPUT EXAMPLE' &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "ERROR CODE 1.1: OK"
else
    echo "ERROR CODE 1.1: BAD"
fi
echo ""
```

How can I modify this to compare against a text file, rather than a literal string?

Comment: Grep is for *finding* strings in a file. For *comparing* files we use `diff`.

Comment: Do you just want to test, whether a certain number of strings occur in the output, or is also the sequence of the strings important?

Comment: I want to compare whether my program output is EXACTLY the same as the given test case text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the provided answers, I was able to answer my own question.
The following modified shell script does what I wanted:

```
cd /
cd media/psf/Home/Developer/Project5/
make

echo "Test 01:"
diff <(./a.out < tests/test01.txt) tests/test01.txt.expected &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "BAD"
fi
echo ""
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of what you intend to achieve:

```
$ cat abcd.c 
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    printf("hello\nworld\n");
}
$ gcc abcd.c 
$ ./a.out 
hello
world
$ cat expected_output 
hello
world
$ diff -q <(./a.out) ./expected_output &> /dev/null 
$ echo $?
0
$ echo "newline" >> ./expected_output 
$ diff -q <(./a.out) ./expected_output &> /dev/null 
$ echo $?
1
$
```

Answer (score 1):

At least if you have Gnu *diff* (as it comes with Linux), which allows to use the special filename `-` to denote stdin, you could do

```
./a.out < tests/test01.txt | diff -- - golden_file.txt
```

to see the differences between the output of a.out and the contents of golden_file.txt. Of course, variations of this approach are possible. Have a look at the options available for `diff`, in particular `--brief`, `--report-identical-files` and `--side-by-side`.

Another possibility is to use `cmp` instead of `diff`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help..

find -name 'filename' | while read f; do [[ "$(grep -o -w -f patterns  $f| sort -u|wc -l)" -eq "$(cat patterns | wc -l)" ]] && echo $f; done